# How can a developer find a paypal webhook secret?

Tags: python, paypal

I've been working with PayPal Developer portal developing a payment and I am now setting up the webhook system to receive responses from PayPal to my endpoint. During this phase, my application must verify the legitimacy of the request and ensure it has come from PayPal. I understand this involves the webhook_id and the webhook_secret. I can't find the webhook_secret on the PayPal developer portal.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

I have searched far and wide and can't seem to find anyone explaining how they actually acquired the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a PayPal REST API call, such as [verify webhook](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/v1/#verify-webhook-signature-post-request-body), then "secret" typically refers to the secret of [a REST App](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications) (specifically, the App for which the webhook and the webhook's transaction correspond to). A clientID and secret is needed for oauth2 authentication, to obtain an access token for PayPal REST API calls.

Comment: So are you suggesting that my app's secret is actually the same thing as my app's webhook secret?

Comment: Unless there's more context about how the term "webhook secret" is being used, yes.